# Taking default value of Int when parameter is passed from Angular service from WebApi controller method

Tags: c#, angular6, asp.net-core-webapi

I am new to Angular and WebApi.
I wanted to retrieve data using a webApi call.
I am trying to call an Api method and passing an id from angular service.
Below is the service.

```
retrieve-data.service.ts

    GetBatchDetailsById(batchId) {
        return this.httpClient.get<IPerson>(this.base_url + 
        'api/SampleData/GetPersonsById', batchId);
    }
```

When I see the webApi method, the parameter is type int and while debugging I see the value as 0.
Could you anyone help me see what I am missing?

*SampleDataController.cs*

```
[Route("api/[controller]")] 
public class SampleDataController : Controller {

    [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
    public Person GetPersonsById(int id)
    {
        return SampleDataController.personList.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Id == id);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you are constructing the request correctly, try `httpClient.get<IPerson>(this.base_url + 
    'api/SampleData/GetPersonsById/' + batchId)`

Comment: Yes, I tried but the webApi method is not hitting at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the route attributes used, the request would need to follow the route template

```
api/SampleData/{id:int}
```

But since you use

```
api/SampleData/GetPersonsById
```

the `GetPersonsById` segment is being taken as the `id` parameter, and since that is not an `int`, it defaults to `0`

Construct your target URL accordingly using the correct format

```
GetBatchDetailsById(batchId) {
    var url = this.base_url + 'api/SampleData/' + batchId;
    return this.httpClient.get<IPerson>(url);
}
```

Reference [Routing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing)

Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)